Get asctime from the logging python lib
I am using the logging python library in order to log some structured JSON.
My idea was to do it manually following the example in the documentation, by giving a config with only the message :
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
And then use json.dumps to log a structured JSON :
logging.info(
     json.dumps({ 
          'my_logger_name': self.my_name,
          'log_level': self.log_level,
          'message': message,
          'some_data': some_data,
    })
)

It works fine, but I would like to add the timestamp to my JSON.dumps. We previously got it by adding %(asctime)s  to the format config.
Is there a way to get it programmatically from the logging library?
I was expecting something like : logging.getLogger().getAsctime()

You can get your current time by using the asctime method from time library, but its important to get your current time first.
import time

your_time = time.localtime()
your_asc= time.asctime(t)

Later you can put this in your json as you want:
  logging.info(
       json.dumps({ 
         'my_logger_name': self.my_name,
         'log_level': self.log_level,
         'message': message,
         'some_data': some_data,
         'time': your_asc
       })

   )


You can get the current time in the format you want by doing:
import time
asctime = time.asctime()

You can add the asctime variable to the JSON object before outputting it as a formatted string.
